# How to layout children in several rows if width of row is exceeded?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

A use case is material design chips that wrap to a new row if all of the chips need to be visible.
How can I accomplish this with Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Flow Layouts. It's not part of the standard Compose library but is developed by Google developers:

https://github.com/google/accompanist/